# how to select all records which has difference of two dates greater than some value

Tags: mysql, oracle

I have a table as below:

```
id    creation_date                      Modify_date
--    -------------                      -----------
1     07/JAN/14 10:11:07.243000000 PM    07/JAN/14 10:16:16.865000000 PM
2     13/JAN/14 12:07:27.603000000 AM    13/JAN/14 12:08:09.955000000 AM
```

I want to select all id which has difference of `Modify_date` and `creation_date` is greater than 5 minutes.

Please suggest how to achieve this, database is oracle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one will help you find the solution

```
select id 
  from tab 
 where (modify_date - creation_date) >=  NUMTODSINTERVAL(5, 'Minute');
```

Change to any minute difference in `NUMTODSINTERVAL(5, 'Minute')`

Comment: below query also worked for me: 

    select *

    from table_name

    where extract(minute from (Modify_date - creation_date) ) >= 5

Comment: `select * from table_name where extract(minute from (Modify_date - creation_date) ) >= 5` has a drawback, consider a scenario that if the difference is 1 hours and 3 minutes, it will not come in the output, but it should, because 1 hours and 3 minutes is greater than 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Subtracting two dates in Oracle result in a day interval, so you just need some multiplications and you're all set:

```
SELECT id
FROM   my_table
WHERE  (modify_date - create_date) * 24 * 60 >= 5
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Select * from table1 where TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, creation_date, Modify_date ) > 5
```